# Removing baseline signal using wavelet transform

Tags: algorithm, time-series, signal-processing, data-processing

I have a received signal level data which looks like this as below :

[image: Signal level data with time]

From this signal, I would like to separate only peaks from the signal. For instance, we can see that signal level deteriorate from the time step 47 and become worse during 53. I would like separate this out from the original signal. I was wondering that wavelet transform could be possible solution for my problem. Please share me your thoughts if you have some other better algorithms to solve this problem.

Your suggestion on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wavelet for sure, although I'm not sure if it's necessary. If you are just trying to identify the time instants where these two peaks occur, they are pretty distinct for direct identification. If you'd like a cleaner separation, you can pass the signal through a wavelet filter, identify the peaks in time and frequency, define a threshold for amplitude separation (but since there are other peaks following them, there's bound to be some mixing), and at last inverse-transform to get the filtered signal.

Comment: Thanks @Melanie Kan, I am trying to check whether this method provides improved result. There are some previous literature where they have tried using linear bypass filter only which already improved result so I am hoping that this will help getting more better result.

Comment: Any one has any idea how I can implement this in Python to remove the baseline...